# Why does a tool not call its constructor or OnActivate() method?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, c#, add-in, tools

I'm working on an add-in for ArcMap 10.0 in .Net version 3.5. It was finely added in arcgis desktop 10.0 as addin tool and working finely. I added some code in the addin project  and build that project again. But At this point, when I run ArcMap and select the tool, the tool is deactivated. In fact, when I put break point on my project and debug it, tool's any method are not called. I wonder, the OnActivate() method is not called either. Even the constructor of the Addin Tool class is not called.

#### Question:

How do I activate my tool now? Why does the tool not call it's constructor or OnActivate() method?

Comment: @Eml, I believe for add-ins you have to use the 'protected override void OnUpdate()', procedure for your enabling or disabling tool events.

Comment: I added 'protected override void OnUpdate()' procedure from when I started to develop this addin. But problem is at debug mode, the addin even didn't call the OnUpdate() method also as I mentioned before.

Comment: If you were unable to resolve this at 10.0, have you tested at 10.1 or 10.2 to see if it persists there?